# How long will it take to update something on a deployed web application?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, web, firebase-hosting

I am very new on Deployment. So I tried to deploy my react app on Firebase. But after that, when I update it, it doesn't seem like the web page will change right away just like in the local. Do I just have to wait or do I have to config something before the update displays on the webpage? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once the deploy to Firebase Hosting completes, the results are also sent to the CDN nodes instantly. If your clients are not seeing the updates, it's most likely because the browser is showing cached results.

You can [control the caching](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/full-config#headers) with `cache-control` headers that you can configure in your `firebase.json` file. Alternatively, you can disable caching for your development site in your browser, or press ctrl-F5/cmd-shift-R to force it to reload the files from the CDN/server.